# Pysimplegui Gui quits updating after table row highlight

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a problem with updating values within my table after a row is clicked. Any other buttons or actions allow for real time value updates from a list that is updated by another function on another thread, but the moment you click highlight on a row the first time, updating quits occuring. Any idea if there is a way to break out of whatever event is causing this?

Table:

```
def table_example():
    global newls7
    global shipnum1
    header_list = ['Item #', 'Item Name', 'Qty', 'Location']
    layout = [
        [sg.Button('Upload Files'), sg.Button('Manual Verification')],[sg.Text('Enter Shipping #:')],
        [sg.Input(shipnum1, enable_events=True, key='-INPUT-'), sg.Button('Ok', key='-OK-')],
        [sg.Table(values=[],
                  headings=header_list,
                  display_row_numbers=False,
                  auto_size_columns=False,
                  max_col_width=40,
                  def_col_width=40,
                  key='-TABLE-',
                  enable_events= True,
                  num_rows=min(25, len(newls7), ))]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Title", layout, resizable=True, finalize=True)
    table = window['-TABLE-'].Widget

    while True:  # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
```

Trying to create table updates with keypressed function due to iterating on a list with two threads, the loop has no problem updating, just the gui interface.

keyboard.press(Key.num_lock)

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('num_lock'):
    window.Element('-TABLE-').update(values=newls7)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Added a timeout which prevented the gui from blocking inputs

```
event, values = window.read(timeout=1)
```